# Android Studio, "local.properties" file has mysteriously incorrect values?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Android experts, using the latest 0.8.11 Android Studio (in fact on a Mac),

I've updated everything and correctly set to use sdk "20" ...

[image]

[image]

.. everything seems to be working great and it seems to build great as a "20" build.

However oddly the local.properties file...

[image]

... seems to be stuck on "19".

In fact, is it just meaningless?  Or now retired, or??

Any info, Android friends?  cheers!

---

Note, it's come to my attention I may have my head up my ass on the "20" ..  i THOUGHT there was a 20 because of ... also note the "API20:" in Yellow in the first image above?!?

[image]

Comment: Dear Joe, there's actually **no Android version 20**. See: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html. So, simply **don't care**.

Comment: Good Lord!  @FrankN.Stein , thank you so much for the info.  I'm totally confused now, note in my first image, it has "API 20", same deal with the image I just added ("Android 4.4W (API 20)" etc ..)  What the heck! :O  Help!

Comment: Ah, I just saw this part:  **"So, simply don't care."**.  **THAT'S GOOD ENOUGH FOR ME** .. thank you!!!

Comment: Your app will work perfectly on currently existing devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API 20/Android 4.4W is for Android Wear (smartwatches).

If you want to target KitKat (4.4), target API 19.